# opencart favicons not showing up, if redirected the admin cannot log in

Tags: redirect, opencart, favicon, broken-links

as suggested in the title, the site is working properly, but if i access it with the www. the favicons are not showing up, if i access the site without the www. the favicons show up fine. I tried redirecting all the users to the site without the www. with the help of the .httaccess file, but then the admin can't log in, the admin works only throught the www.site. I tried to change the config.php file, but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself eventually.
needed to put this line inside the `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the favicon icon link in head of the html pages of your site with the following. Also the path of icon file should start with www -

```
<link rel="icon" href="your_path_to_icon_file" type="image/x-icon">
```